# How to create a custom VSIX wizard based on the Visual studio's theme selected

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix, vs-extensibility, vsixmanifest

I have a requirement to create a custom vsix (visual studio extension project) wizard which is a single windows form, I developed it considering the dark theme selected in visual studio. Hence the window background in the wizard steps are shown in dark background. When user changes the visual studio theme to light background, the wizard dialog colors are contradictory to that of background visual studio theme. Is there a easy way to access the background theme which was set in visual studio programmatically in C#? And based on that theme can I develop other dialog windows and display it to the user? In short can I do something shown as below in pseudo code?

```
if(VS.Theme == Dark)
{
ShowDarkWizard();
}
else if(VS.Theme == Light)
{
ShowLightWizard();
}
else if(VS.Theme == Blue)
{
ShowBlueWizard();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your wizard dialog is implemented by deriving from [DialogWindow Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.platformui.dialogwindow) (which it probably should be if you're using WPF), you can leverage the [VsBrushes Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.vsbrushes) in your XAML markup to mirror VS styles.

Sincerely,

Comment: Unfortunately, I developed Wizard using WinForms. Any other way to fetch the theme in a program?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you might be able to use IVsUIShell5.ThemeWindow. There's also some docs covering some of this at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/ux-guidelines/colors-and-styling-for-visual-studio?view=vs-2019